# Asymptotic analysis of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have a function of the form $f(\theta) = \exp(-\theta I)$, where $I$ is a constant. I read in a paper that $f(\theta) \sim \exp(-\Theta(\theta))$ as $\theta \to \infty$.

Why should it hold only when $\theta \to \infty? $ Should it not hold for all values of $\theta$?

Comment: What is $\Theta(\theta)$ ?

Comment: A statement involving $\Theta$ is a statement about limits.  See [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  It would be meaningless to make a statement of the form "$\ldots \Theta(\theta) \ldots$ for all values of $\theta$."

Comment: $f(x) = \Theta(g(x))$ if $f(x) = \mathcal{O(g(x)}$ and $g(x) = \mathcal{O(f(x)}$; $f(x) = \mathcal{O(g(x))}$ if $f(x)/g(x)$ remains bounded